# Angular CDK Portal not being created by @ViewChild?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cdk

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-portal-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-actions.component.ts) attempts to create a CDK Portal like this:

```
@ViewChild(CdkPortal) portal;
```

However the portal is undefined in the `ngAfterViewInit` Method:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Create a portalHost from a DOM element
    this.portalHost = new DomPortalHost(
      document.querySelector('#actions'),
      this.componentFactoryResolver,
      this.appRef,
      this.injector
    );

    console.log("THE PORTAL IS: ", this.portal)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to import the portal module:

```
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

...


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ PortalModule, MaterialModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ ToolbarActionsComponent, AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```